# Node.js script seems to skip fs.readFile code block

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, switch-statement

I'm trying to use Node.js to append a `.json` file using `fs`.

I have written `const fs = require("fs");` at the top of my document, but within a `switch` and `case` block, where much of the code is run normally, the entire `fs.readFile(...)` section doesn't seem to do anything.

Also, for the purposes of simplicity, lets say I've defined `initCommand` as `process.argv[2]` and `whatToSet` as `process.argv[3]`

here is the whole `switch` and `case` block for the `case` in question:

```
switch(initCommand) {
    case("set"):
        newObject = {
            whatToSet: whatToSet,
            whenToSet: Date.now(),
        };
        console.log(newObject);
        console.log("top of fs code block");
        fs.readFile('objects.json', function (err, data) {
            let json = [];
            if (!err) {
                try {
                    json = JSON.parse(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            }
            json.push(newObject);
            fs.writeFile("objects.json", JSON.stringify(json), function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(`Your "object" was successfully appended!`);
            });
        });
        console.log("bottom of fs code block");
    break;
}
```

And when I run the command from the command line, calling the "set" `case`, `node index.js set attribute` here is the output:

```
{ whatToSet: 'attribute', whenToSet: 1516730036191 }
top of fs code block
bottom of fs code block
```

And needless to say, `objects.json` remains untouched. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit: Found a rogue `process.exit();` that was cancelling the async `fs` process. Code runs correctly now. I also updated that `fs.readFile(...)...` bit above based on everyone's advice.

Comment: You know that `'object: ' + newObject` is `'object' : [Object object]` ? And you are not handling errors! Do that!

Comment: How do you know that `fs.readFile` is not encountering an error? You didn't check to see if it is.

Comment: I've added another error handling statement for the `fs.readFile`, but still no `err` is being thrown

Comment: @JonasW. if I could even get it to append my .json with `'object': [Object object]` I would be on the right track

Comment: Try to update your code with sync version of your async code. Use `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.writeFileSync`. By the way, what version of node are you using?

Comment: Ok so you added the error check here, but did you actually run it? Is it able to read `objects.json`? Have you tried logging out the `data` when it reads it?

Comment: Try writing console.error(err) instead of throw err
I'm not sure whether it will actually show you the error when run inside of a callback

Comment: Also, how big is the file? maybe it just takes a while to read

Comment: Did you tried on LTS node version?

Comment: FYI, `if (err) throw err;` is NEVER an appropriate error handler inside an async callback.  When starting with async development, start with appropriate error handling from day one.  Don't leave that to be learned later.

Comment: @gforce301 I cannot seem to log the data either. Or really do anything within the fs code block. @MaxJöhnk not big at all, and I've tried `console.error(error)` now with same result. @Yurii I have not.

Comment: Tried with earlier (stable) build of node. Tried adding and revising error handling. Tried using `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync`. Still getting the same results. I wont be surprised if it's something obvious I've overlooked.

Comment: found a rogue `process.exit();` that was cancelling out the async process here. Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file `objects.json` exists, that it contains a valid JSON, and that the JSON represents an array (like `[]`). If the file contains an object (`{}`), the call to `.push` will fail.

If you don't care about the possibility of losing some data in case of error, you can try something like this:

```
newObject = {
    whatToSet: whatToSet,
    whenToSet: Date.now(),
};
console.log(newObject);
console.log("top of fs code block");
fs.readFile('objects.json', function (err, data) {
    let json = [];
    if (!err) {
        try {
            json = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
    json.push(newObject);
    fs.writeFile("objects.json", JSON.stringify(json), function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Your "object" was successfully appended!`);
    });
});
console.log("bottom of fs code block");
```

I tested this code on Node v8.4.0 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying it with your code. Not concerned about losing data with my current set up, using a test `.json` file with a tiny array of one innocuous object inside it. How can I be sure my JSON is valid? I created a file using `touch objects.json` and then put my little array inside manually. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? You can even delete your original file and run it, it should create a new objects.json. If you don’t see the file, maybe you are looking in the wrong place. You could try using the absolute path instead of just the file name to test.

Comment: Thanks again! You helped me get on the right track. After testing your code alone (which worked) I tested it plugged into my larger document, and ultimately determined the problem was outside of this block, so I searched around and discovered a `process.exit()` function further along that was being run, thereby cancelling the async `fs` process.